# how to insert to a mysql table using mysaldb, where the table name is in a python variable?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm using python-mysql db api to insert some values to a table where the table name is in a python variable. So I wrote the below code

```
DB_CURSOR.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (name,created_by,state,description,docs,admin_email,date_created) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (hosts_table, hostname, created_by, state, description, docroot, admin_email, date_created))
```

As you see the table name is in the hosts_table variable. The problem is mysqldb quotes the table name and i get a mysql error. It works fine when I literally use the table name. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DB_CURSOR.execute("""INSERT INTO %s 
    (name,created_by,state,description,docs,admin_email,date_created) 
    VALUES(%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)""" % hosts_table,
    (hostname, created_by, state, description, docroot, admin_email, date_created))
```

Note that the hosts_table variable is a single % sign, and all the other variables are two %% so they are ignored in the initial Python string interpolation, then change to a single % for the mysqldb part.

Try this in the Python prompt to see what I mean:

```
>>> '%%s %s' % 'x'
'%s x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
DB_CURSOR.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (name,created_by,state,description,docs,admin_email,date_created) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" % (hosts_table), (hostname, created_by, state, description, docroot, admin_email, date_created))
```

I'm not sure it will work but it could :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb does not care a bit about the names of your variables. If you are having a problem with the table name, try to assign `hosts_table` to the name of your table, and see if it'll work.

`hosts_table = 'hosts_table'`

Or just `print` it out and see what table name it's using:

`print hosts_table`

Comment: It's not a variable naming issue. The problem is MySQLdb treats the table name variable in the same way it treats the column names. So it quotes the value thinking of it as a string column.