# Using %s commands in execute statements (python) in mySQL vs postgreSQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql

I've been writing code recently in python that works with postgreSQL databases, and it looks like the following:

```
def insert(table, ID, date, timestamp):
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (ID, date, timest)
                   VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""", 
                   (AsIs(table), ID, AsIs(date), AsIs(timestamp)))
```

This seems to work fine for postgreSQL, but when I try the same thing on a mySQL server, it doesn't work. Does anybody have an idea as to why? I think it might have to do with the %s characters, as it works if I hardcode in the values for table, ID, date, and timestamp.

In addition, it gives me the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''master'' at line 2")
```

'master' is the name of the table I used as a variable, and I also noticed that there were two single quotes around master (like so: ' 'master' '), where there should only be one. So this might be a problem too?

Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you create the string before giving the `execute` command?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense how would I do that?

Comment: `query_str = "INSERT INTO %s (ID, date, timest) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);" % (str(table), str(ID), str(date), str(timestamp))` followed by `cur.execute(query_str)`. I dunno if this will work, I haven't used Python's SQL libraries.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense -- That's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: But, it seems like the table name shouldn't be quoted, should it?

Comment: Whoops, well now I know why it's done that way.

Comment: `AsIS` is a `psycopg2` adapter. What driver are you using for MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert to a mysql table using mysaldb, where the table name is in a python variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936806/how-to-insert-to-a-mysql-table-using-mysaldb-where-the-table-name-is-in-a-pytho)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I am using MySQLdb for my driver. Is there something analogous for MySQL?

Comment: I can't find `AsIs` in the MySQLdb manual. Post the exact code that produces that error

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Actually, I got it figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Actually, I was able to figure out the answer to my question. Simply using a % instead of the , notation fixed my problem.

Original code:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (ID, date, timest)
               VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""", 
               (AsIs(table), ID, AsIs(date), AsIs(timestamp)))
```

Fixed code:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (ID, date, timest)
               VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""" %
               (AsIs(table), ID, AsIs(date), AsIs(timestamp)))
```

Comment: NO NO NO. Please don't do that because it's a [horribly insecure SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @KirkStrauser I realize it is prone to SQL injection, but it is merely a test script that I will be running for a known set of tables for my own use.

Comment: There's no such thing as an unloaded gun or a secured query. Both should be treated as highly dangerous and likely to explode at any moment. Doing things the right way is exactly as easy as doing them the wrong way, so it's better to get in the habit of doing it right every single time.

Comment: @KirkStrauser but it seems the way of doing it "right" is to manually hard code each of my table names, which would have been pretty inefficient given the way my code operates. This is a viable shortcut that meets the conditions that I need.

Comment: At the very least, you could write `"INSERT INTO %s (var, var) VALUES (%%s, %%s)" % table_name` so that the table name is injected into the string but that the values still go through safe escaping.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work fine in PostgreSQL either. The table name should not be parametrized.

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO table_name_here (ID, date, timest) ...
```

For string concatenation: Postgres uses SQL-standard double quotes (*not* two single quotes!): `"master"`, which does not work in default MySQL. Would have to be `` `master` `` - or just `master` to work in both.

Or activate a setting for some SQL-compliance in MySQL:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use format function:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO {0} (ID, date, timest) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);".format(table_name)
cursor.execute(sql, (ID, date, time_stamp))
```