# Python 2.7 to MariaDB SQL error

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to insert data into a sequel table using variables. The following statement is the one causing errors:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (avg_time,max_time) VALUES (%s,%s)", (SOURCE, reav, remax))
```

The error is:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near ''USA' (avg_time,max_time)
>   VALUES ('6.997','7.071')' at line 1")

Anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: what library are you using to connect? the problem is with how you are inserting the table name but I can't help until I know the library you're using

Comment: I'm totally new to programming but I have an import statement: 

import MySQLdb   --- That means the library is MySQLdb, right?

Comment: are you sure the table name can be given with `%s` ?

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi in `psycopg2` you can using the `AsIs` function but I am not sure that `MySQLdb` has a variation of that

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi you were spot on. SQL didn't like the table name being a variable. I saved the entire SQL command as a str variable in python, and passed that variable to the cursor.execute() function. It worked. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (avg_time,max_time) VALUES (%s,%s)", (SOURCE, reav, remax))
```

To this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (avg_time,max_time) VALUES (%%s,%%s)" % SOURCE, (reav, remax))
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936806/how-to-insert-to-a-mysql-table-using-mysaldb-where-the-table-name-is-in-a-pytho)

Although this would seem to be prone to SQL injection with the table name given it's using string formatting.